# Incorrect question sorting

Tags: bug

Description:

When sorting the questions on the [main site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) by the number of votes, the sorting is not done correctly. What I mean is that a single page will contain questions from x votes up until y votes (where x and y are very very far apart, something like +50 and -10).

Steps to reproduce:

- go to the [main site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)
- click on "Questions"
- click on "votes", to sort them by votes
- go, for example to page 6 (in my case, 15 questions per page is selected)
- see that the top of the page has a question with score +48, at the bottom there is one with score -8 (minus eight)
- go to the next page (7), the questions should have a score less than or equal to -8. Instead, they start with score +45.

I looked at 2 other StackExchange sites and couldn't reproduce the problem, so it must be specific to The Workplace.

Comment: That is...odd...I get the same behavior. Let's blame caching! (until a dev or community manager clears this up, then let's kill the messenger!)